# Mapping of Transfer Attribute node is confusing

Tags: geometry-nodes

Signed angle is connected to the viewer with and without transfer attribute node in between, see pics below. The sixth and seventh points are circled out in 3d viewport and they have an attribute 0.393 without the transfer attribute node, which is the average over 4 linked edges.

However when we use "Nearest faces interpolated" mode for transfer attribute, one becomes 0 and the other becomes 1.125. This I cannot understand. Shouldn't these two points be symmetric along z axis therefore have the same value? How can I get this 0 and 1.125?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Domain interpolation can be finicky regardles, but I'm not getting the same result yo do, they both get 0 or 0.314. With Transfer: https://i.imgur.com/gqFztVx.png without:  https://i.imgur.com/d9p0Z8S.png Can you share your file?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I found that when Transfer attribute is in the tree, the attribute changes if one tweaks the length of the model along axis in edit mode. For example, you can drag the most right face along x axis and the numbers in the viewer change as if there's a critical point. This is my file https://drive.google.com/file/d/108mOVkKCsD5MDsL8NRQmdsZu-wS2tcCW/view?usp=share_link